# UIAutomatorViewer doesn't work with Android 8

Tags: android, adb, android-uiautomator, uiautomatorviewer

I'm developing automatization programm with ADB. I use UIAutomatorViewer to find elements on my phone, that has Android 7.1.2 version. It works fine with it, but recently I needed to use another phone on Android 8.1.0 version. I connected it via USB, checked the connection by 'adb devices' - yes, it connected. But when I opened UIAutomatorViewer and tried to take a XML dumpscreen, the program gave this error:
Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

I already has rebooted UIAutomatorViewer, my phone and PC, it didnt help. Appium server is off. Java version - 1.8.0_172. Pay attention that the programm works excelent with Android 7.1.2. All phones are Xiaomi.
Please, help me. I've been trying to fix this for a week and haven't found any information about it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try the same versions on an emulator to verify